# Checking membership in large ordered list?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I have a piece of code in C that generates a lot of numbers sequentially, and I want to check if these numbers are in a sorted list. The list was created using numpy, and has ~10<sup>9</sup> elements, which, as mentioned, are ordered from least to greatest. What is the absolute fastest way for my C code to check if its result is in this list? Which data structure should I use (if I include the C++ STL)? I was thinking that binary search on an unordered map might be fastest, but I'm not sure.

Furthermore (and this is probably the most important thing) how should I include the list of numbers in my program - just copy and paste it into my file? Or perhaps venture into SQLite or another database?

Comment: You can't do a binary search on an unordered_map.  A binary search needs sorted data and an unordered_map has no ordering.

Comment: My bad, you're right NathanOliver.

Comment: If you load all the values into memory you can do an O(1) search on an unordered set or an O(log n) binary search on a vector. However, it may not be wise to load gigabytes of numbers into memory. An on-disk solution would be smarter and, yes, at that point you'd be well advised to use a database.

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically, the C program is a loop that returns a number. I have a long list of numbers, and I want to check if the number returned from the C program is in the list, very much like the Python `in` operator.

Comment: Testing the overlap between one sorted list and another is pretty trivial and doesn't require binary searches or anything fancy at all. Compare the first two elements, then just walk through, incrementing pointers when one value becomes higher than the other.

Comment: So you have two big sorted lists and want to check which numbers from list A is present in list B. Is that it?

Comment: I forgot to add to my original post, the largest number in my list is 1.3*10^9

Comment: @4386427, no, I have a single number and want to check if that number is present in list A; there is no list B.

Comment: @DataScienceNovice How much memory are you willing to use 256M, 512M, 1G or ...?

Comment: You could use [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search).

Comment: @DataScienceNovice How important is program start up time compared to fast look-up?

Comment: I have up to 16 GB to use - this is the only program that will be running on the computer.

Comment: Will all numbers in the list be unique?

Comment: @4386427 startup time is far less important than execution time once everything's been loaded into memory

Comment: Yes, every element of the list is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is sorted. Just use the **C** standard library [`bsearch`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.1p1) function with an *array*. If you've produced them with Numpy, then write these to *file* as a *binary*, *in order*, i.e.

```python
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(1, 3000000, 3, dtype='int32')
array.tofile('array.bin')
```

and use `mmap` if in Unix/Linux to map it into memory, read-only:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   const int32_t *A = a, *B = b;
   return (*A > *B) - (*A < *B);
}

bool is_in_array(int32_t *base, size_t length, int32_t element) {
    return bsearch(&element, base, length, sizeof (int32_t), cmpfunc);
}

int main(void) {
    int fd = open("array.bin", O_RDONLY);
    struct stat statbuf;

    fstat(fd, &statbuf);
    size_t length = statbuf.st_size;
    void *base = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    size_t elements = length / sizeof(int32_t);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 3 * elements; i += 10000) {
        printf("%" PRId32 " is %sin the set\n", i,
             is_in_array(base, elements, i) ? "" : "not ");
    }

    munmap(base, length);
    close(fd);
}
```

---

`bsearch` is not necessarily absolutely fastest, but it isn't bad. If it is too slow, then you can consider inlining the algorithm.

---

If the number range indeed is as small as 0 to 1.3G, then you can organize it as a bitmap. However, if your numbers were say int64 or md5 hashes, a bitmap wouldn't work.

For bitmap, you can use

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(1, 3000000, 3, dtype='int32')
bytearray = np.zeros(array.max() + 1, dtype='bool')
bytearray[array] = 1
bitarray = np.packbits(bytearray)
bitarray.tofile('bitarray.bin')
```

and:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    int fd = open("bitarray.bin", O_RDONLY);

    fstat(fd, &statbuf);
    size_t length = statbuf.st_size;
    unsigned char *base = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    size_t limit = length * CHAR_BIT;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < limit + 30000; i += 10000) {
        bool is_in = false;
        if (i < limit) {
            size_t index = i / CHAR_BIT;
            int bit = i % CHAR_BIT;
            is_in = (base[index] & (1 << bit));
        }

        printf("%" PRIu32 " is %sin the set\n", i,
             is_in ? "" : "not ");
    }

    munmap(base, length);
    close(fd);
}
```

---

Of course, the *easiest* would be to do **either** thing in Python - Numpy has binary search in form of [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy.searchsorted).

Comment: Saving the bitmap directly from python and simply mmap it in C is pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

The theoretically fastest way, and probably also in practice, is O(1): use a bitmap, i.e. `std::vector<bool>` (which has a special implementation that uses only one bit per entry). Set bit `i` to true if and only if it's in your original list. This lets you do the check with a single memory fetch. The drawback is that this might cost more memory than you have, depending on the largest number in the list.

If that doesn't fit, you can consider `std::set` (O(n log n)), `std::unordered_set` (O(1)) or a sorted `std::vector` with binary search (O(n log n)). Measure to see which is fastest.

If that's still not performant enough, you could also look into using a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) as a quick check to exclude many misses before you start the slower search.

Answer (score 0):

In C code I would use a simple array of unsigned integers and let each bit represent a number. This will require approx. 200MB of memory. If your system has 8G and this is the only running program, I guess 200MB is a fair price for fast look-ups.

The look-up function could simply be:

```
bool check(uint32_t value, uint32_t* arr)
{
    uint32_t tmp = arr[value >> 5];
    return tmp & (1 << (value & 0x1F));
}
```

The Numpy data you just place in a txt-file that you read at start-up.

For each value from Numpy call a function like:

```
void set(uint32_t value, , uint32_t* arr)
{
    uint32_t idx = value >> 5;
    arr[idx] = arr[idx] | (1  << (value & 0x1F));
}
```

Before inserting any Numpy value, you dynamic allocate the array using `calloc`. Like:

```
uint32_t numpyVal;
uint32_t* arr = calloc(MAX_NUM/32, sizeof *arr);
while(getNextNumpyValue(&numpyVal) 
{
   set(numpyVal, arr);
}

if (check(SOME_VALUE, arr)
{
    printf("Found\n");
}
```